# How does throw new exception inside a catch work?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I have a snippet as follows:

```
try
{
   //blah!!
} 
catch(IOException e)
{
   throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

I do not understand how the above works? Will it `catch` an `IOException` and when it does that will it `throw` a `RuntimeException`? In that case the `IOException` will not have any meaning right? Some example would help.

Comment: You are correct. It is very useful when you want throw your own exception instead of system default (e.g. change exception message or add some hints what went wrong and how to fix it)

Comment: Yes, the above code would catch (and discard) the IOException, then throw a RuntimeException.  Not necessarily good coding practice, but perfectly legal Java.  An exception is an object, and, once caught, has no special status vs any other object -- it can be ignored (and cleaned up by GC), passed as a parameter, rethrown, whatever.

Comment: @Hot Licks the IOException is wrapped in the RuntimeException which is not necessarily bad if you don't like checked exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right about some assumptions, but you should go a bit deeper.
Inside your `try` block, suppose one of your methods of your class throws this kind of exception `IOException`. So catch will work as way for you to treat this exceptional case. It's basically this. If you just throw your exception away using a RuntimeException, but as you did, wrapping your `IOException` in `RuntimeException` you won't lose it at all.

A normal use is in a higher level treat your exception. Here's a good tutorial about Exception Handling, please check: [Best Practices for Exception Handling](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/11/19/exceptions.html)

Answer (score 1):

In this code the checked IOException becomes effectively unchecked. By passing the IOException into the RuntimeException you are chaining the 2 together.

Answer (score 1):

Yes your understanding is correct. This may be useful in cases where you want to display application specific exceptions instead of java provided exceptions  (IOException may not be perfect case to understand this).

Answer (score 1):

Checked `Exceptions` have to be caught or declared as thrown.  `RuntimeExceptions` do not, so catching and rethrowing as a `RuntimeException` is way to avoid having to declare:

```
public void myMethod() throws IOException
```

When `throw new RuntimeException(e);` is called a new exception is created an thrown, but the original exception is wrapped inside it.  So the stack trace will look like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Some error.
    at com...main(SomeClass.java:36)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Some error.
```

So the actual exception that goes up the call stack was a `RuntimeException` but the original `IOException` is kept in the message as the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct.  If an `IOException` is thrown, the `catch` handler will catch it, then immediately throw its own `RuntimeException`.  This exception might be caught elsewhere in the program, in which case control will pick up at the handler, or it will be uncaught and will terminate the current thread.

One way to think about what's going on here is the following - an `IOException` is checked exception, which means that it must be caught.  If it's not caught, then the program won't compile.  The above code says that whenever it catches an `IOException`, it will throw a `RuntimeException`, which is an unchecked exception.  This exception doesn't have to be caught if the programmer doesn't want to catch it.  Notice that this `RuntimeException` is constructed with the caught `IOException` as a parameter.  This means that if the `RuntimeException` is later caught, whoever catches it can notice that the underlying reason was an `IOException` and can handle it accordingly.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

No. There is something special to RuntimeException. When you want to throw a RuntimeException, you don't need a `throws RuntimeException` in the method signature. This is called an unchecked exception. This code wraps the IOException into a RuntimeException and rethrows it to the caller, which is IMHO a bad approach, in most cases.

All subclasses of RuntimeException are unchecked, like IllegalArgumentException, NullPointerException, etc...

Comment: There's nothing particularly special about RuntimeException vs many other exceptions.  It is "unchecked", but that's purely a compiler convention (the JVM knows nothing of the concept), and there are a number of other "unchecked" exceptions.

Comment: It's often the least bad option in Java, e.g. when implementing an interface that you don't control (part of an API). You don't want to discard an exception, but you're not allowed to let it escape the interface method. Simple example: `Runnable.run` - so you throw RuntimeException instead.

Comment: @DanielEarwicker: Yes, I was thinking about that as well, fair point. But Runnable.run is a bad example, I think. Because you don't call the run method yourself. It is called by another thread. When an exception is thrown, the thread will die and the other part of the application will not know it.